# How to revert div1 when div2 is dragged and dropped?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to create a script (see code snippet) to *revert* `element1` when `element2` is *dropped*.
I'm using *jQuery* `drag` and `drop` functions.

Right now there is a `Reset` button, that resets all the elements. However, I don't like that.
*I don't want to reset all elements.*
Instead, I want `element1` to be *reverted* when `element2` is *dropped* on it (and vice versa).

*Here is an image of how I want the revert function to work (the bullets below describe the arrows):*

[image]

- **Arrow 1:** `element1` is *dragged and dropped* in the drop zone.
- **Arrow 2:** `element2` is being *dragged*.
- **Arrow 3:** `element1` is being *reverted* when `element2` is *dropped*.

Can you help me with it?

***Code Snippet:***

```js
$("#element1, #element2").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  scroll: false
});

$("#drop").droppable({
  drop: handleDropEvent,
  accept: "#element1, #element2"
});
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  ui.draggable.position({ of:$(this), my:'center', at:'center' });
}

$("#Reset").click(function() {
  $("#element1, #element2").animate({
    "left": $("#element1, #element2").data("left"),
    "top": $("#element1, #element2").data("top")
  });
});

$("#element1, #element2").data("left", $("#element1, #element2").position().left).data("top", $("#element1, #element2").position().top);
```

```css
#element1{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
#element2{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
#drop {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="element1"></div>
<div id="element2"></div>

<div id="drop">Drop here</div>
<button type="button" id="Reset" name="button">Reset</button>
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jwrno71z/1/**

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the following code (in the `drop:` handler) does the trick:

```
$(".drop").droppable({
  accept: /*other code*/
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if ($(this).data("draggable")) {revertDraggables($(this).data("draggable"));}
    $(this).data("draggable", "."+ui.draggable[0].className.substring(0,ui.draggable[0].className.indexOf("ui-")-1).replace(/ /g,".")); //store the draggable's classes as selector (first remove the standard ui-classes)
    ui.draggable.position({of:this, my:"center", at:"center"});
  }
}).data("draggable","");
```

- First, it checks if there already is a (previously stored) *draggable* on the *droppable*. If so, it reverts that *draggable* to its start-position.
- Then, it stores the current *draggable* in the *droppable's* `data` attribute `"draggable"`.
  I'll explain what that line does:

  - `ui.draggable[0].className` gets the string of all class-names of the current *draggable*.
  - The complete `className` of a *draggable* is:
    `"drop1 drag one ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging"`.
    Only the first three classes are your own custom classes, the other classes are automatically added/removed by *jQuery UI*.
  - `.substring(0,className.indexOf("ui-")-1)` creates a [**substring**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) starting from the first character in the className-string, to the [**first occurrence**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) of `"ui-"`, `-1` to also remove the empty space in front of it ("ui-" is, as you can see, the prefix for all ui-classes).
    RESULT: `"drop1 drag one"`
  - `.replace(/ /g,".")` replaces all empty spaces by dots (using [**regular expression**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)), so the className-string can be used as a jQuery-selector. The `"."+` at the start of the line also prepends a dot at the very start of the string.
    RESULT: `".drop1.drag.one"`
- Last, it positions the current *draggable* on the *droppable* (your own code).
- *(The `.data("draggable","")` at the end is just setting the `data` attribute. It's the same as writing `$(".drop").data("draggable","");`, except now it's [**chained**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp) directly after the `.droppable()`.)*

---

But I changed a couple of other things too, check out the code snippet:

```js
function revertDraggables(selector) {
  $(selector).animate({"left":$(selector).data("left"), "top":$(selector).data("top")});
}

$(".drag").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  scroll: false
}).data("left",$(".drag").position().left).data("top",$(".drag").position().top); //set draggables' position-data-attribute

$(".drop").droppable({
  accept: function(draggable) {return draggable.hasClass(this.className.split(" ")[0]);}, //accept draggable if it has the same class as this droppable's first class
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if ($(this).data("draggable")) {revertDraggables($(this).data("draggable"));} //revert previously dropped draggable
    $(this).data("draggable", "."+ui.draggable[0].className.substring(0,ui.draggable[0].className.indexOf("ui-")-1).replace(/ /g,".")); //store the draggable's classes as selector (first remove the standard ui-classes)
    ui.draggable.position({of:this, my:"center", at:"center"}); //position draggable on droppable
  }
}).data("draggable","");

$(".reset").click(function() {
  var group = this.className.split(" ")[0]; //store the group-identifying classname
  revertDraggables(".drag."+group); //revert all draggables (belonging to this reset-button)
  $(".drop."+group).data("draggable",""); //clear the droppable's draggable-data-attribute
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.drag {width:50px; height:50px; z-index:1;}
.drag.one {background-color:black;}
.drag.two {background-color:red;}

.drop {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="drop1 drag one"></div>
  <div class="drop1 drag two"></div>
  <div class="drop1 drop">Drop here</div>
  <button type="button" class="drop1 reset" name="button">Reset</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="drop2 drag one"></div>
  <div class="drop2 drag two"></div>
  <div class="drop2 drop">Drop here</div>
  <button type="button" class="drop2 reset" name="button">Reset</button>
</div>
```

***jsfiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/jwrno71z/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/jwrno71z/4/_)***

- I changed the id-selectors (`id="element1"` and `$("#element1")`) to class-selectors (`class="drag one"` and `$(".drag")`). This makes your code more flexible, because now you don't have to add every draggable element in your JS-code. Same for droppable elements.
  *I also changed your CSS to classes, making it more flexible as well.*
- I gave all *draggables*, *droppables* and *reset buttons* a shared class (`drop1`, `drop2`, etc.), so you can have multiple drag&drop-systems on one page, without having to update your JS.
  *You only have to copy/paste a `<div class="container">` and change the `drop1` classes to the next free number.*
- `this.className.split(" ")[0]` takes the className-string (for instance `"drop1 drop"`) and creates an array out of that, [**splitting**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) the values on an empty space. And then, it takes the first value in that array (at index `[0]`), so `"drop1"`.
- The `<div class="container">` elements need to have `position:relative;` in CSS, in order for the positioning of the *draggables* to work correctly.
- I gave the *draggables* `z-index:1;` in CSS, otherwise the *draggables* of the *first droppable* would disappear under the *second droppable*.